# List multiple directories in php

Tags: php

I am using the following call in php:

```
foreach(glob('../music/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $playlist) {
```

How can I modify this to search more than one directory...
i.e. `foreach(glob('../music/*' && '../books/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $playlist) {`

?

Comment: you need 2 separate loops

Comment: But Ive seen it before when somehow two directories were included?

Comment: you can try `foreach(array_merge(glob('../music/*'), glob('../books/*'))...`

Comment: @Lashane In this case you don’t need separate loops, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
glob('../{music,books}/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_BRACE)
```

**UPD** Further processing as requested in comments:

```
- $playlist = str_replace('../music/', '', $playlist);
+ $playlist = preg_replace('/\.\.\/(music|books)\//', '', $playlist);
```

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) comes to the scene, because now you need to search for regular expression, not simple string. Hope it helps.

**UPD** Or, with [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$playlist = str_replace(array('../music/','../books/'), '', $playlist);
```

Comment: Looks as if this will work but I have a follow up line that strips the path and just shows the file name ---- $playlist = str_replace('../music/', '', $playlist); ---- can you advise me on what I should replace the '../music/' with so that it gets both the music and books dirs?

Comment: 1- foreach(glob('../{music,books}/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_BRACE) as $playlist) {
2- $album_dir = $playlist; // maintain full dir path for album art   
3- $playlist = str_replace('../music/', '', $playlist);  // When I use these three lines, I use your suggestion in line 1, but in line 3, I use the '../music' again... how would I include the '../books' in line 3. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: '../{music,books}/*' in place of '../music' ?